# How to do URL Embeding Allowing One Website Resource Accessible from Other Web Site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There are 2 web site A, B. Web site A  has a resource, such as http://www.a.com/resource1. Web site B has a page http://www.b.com/page1, which has content. And I want http://www.a.com/resource1 to be part of the content.

It is like youtube, you can embed youtube video into other web site page in another web site.

I am looking for a basic example, which demonstrates how this is done. Front end HTML, iframe, javascript pseudo code is good enough.

Comment: So... this kind of stuff is on a lot of sites. Many sites include scripts and images from other domains. It is extremely common. So, I am guessing that you are not referring to these types of resources. Are you talking about some json file or something else? What kind of resource from A will you be using on B. If it is scripts, the answer is simple. If you want b.com to access an endpoint on the a.com backend, that is much more complicated. Can you be more specific in what you would like to see here?

Comment: Hi frosty, thank you for reply. To be more specific, Site A has resource of text and image display, for example, a page A_p1 with text and image. A_p1 content is from javascript through web service API. Site A is my site. Site B is another site, which integrate site A page A_p1 content into site B page B_p1. When integrated, A_p1 is part of B_p1. How B_p1 integrate A_p1 content is beyond my control. It's like youtube, you can embed youtube anywhere in a page you develop. I am looking for a example, so that I can start to do it myself. I would appreciate it if you provide more specific example.